# Bash sort by number AND word length AND alphabetically

Tags: bash, sorting, numeric

I have these strings in my array:

```
3 rere 33.33%
2 ena 22.22%
1 something 11.11%
1 som 11.11%
1 ok 11.11%
1 evo 11.11%
```

Expected results are:

```
3 rere 33.33%
2 ena 22.22%
1 something 11.11%
1 evo 11.11%
1 som 11.11%
1 ok 11.11%
```

They are ordered by number descending.

And I want to order them also by length of word in middle, but if words are same length, order them alphabetically.

These are not columns.

I wanted to split it in two arrays and sort them afterwards, but how to join them together?
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Can you add your expected output? You write "they are ordered by number descending, and I want to order them *also* by length of word" - which one is it? Or should that be first by number, then by length of word, then alphabetically? Also, I don't understand the "These are not columns" sentence. Are there commas missing?

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of extending it in comments.

Comment: Are you limited to using *only* bash for this, or are other standard shell tools available on your system like `awk`, `sort`, etc?

Comment: @ghoti Judging by comment on answer, at least `sort` is available.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - yep, I see that, just trying to encourage the OP to be more explicit in the question. :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind this is very similar to the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) used in [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897027/3266847): we add a sort field (in this case the length of the second column), use it to sort, then remove it again:

```
while read -r col1 word rest; do
    printf "%d\t%s %s %s\n" "${#word}" "$col1" "$word" "$rest"
done < infile | sort -k 2,2nr -k 1,1nr -k 3,3 | cut -f 2
```

This results in

```
3 rere 33.33%
2 ena 22.22%
1 something 11.11%
1 evo 11.11%
1 som 11.11%
1 ok 11.11%
```

After the while loop, the output looks like this:

```
4   3 rere 33.33%
3   2 ena 22.22%
9   1 something 11.11%
3   1 som 11.11%
2   1 ok 11.11%
3   1 evo 11.11%
```

There is a new column with the length of the string in the second column. It's tab separated for easier `cut`ting afterwards.

For `sort`, we specify what to use for sorting with the `-k` arguments (`sort` doesn't care if the fields are tab or space separated): `2,2nr` uses just the second field, numerically and in descending order; the same goes for `1,1nr`, and `3,3` is just your standard lexical sort.

The output now looks like this:

```
4   3 rere 33.33%
3   2 ena 22.22%
9   1 something 11.11%
3   1 evo 11.11%
3   1 som 11.11%
2   1 ok 11.11%
```

Now we only have to get rid of the first column, for which we use `cut` and take advantage of the tab separation introduced with `printf`.

The Bash while loop is very slow, the Perl solution is likely orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: THANKS MAN... IT DID IT... thank you very much :D exactly what i needed

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort by length with `sort`. Let's try a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
awk '{print length($2), $0}' file | sort -k2,2nr -k1,1nr -k3,3 | cut -d" " -f2-
```

The awk command takes `1 something 11.11%` and outputs `9 1 something 11.11%`.
Then sort sorts first by the 2nd field numerically, then by the 1st field numerically, then by the 3rd field lexically.
Then cut removes the first field.

Comment: Nice link you got there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -l -0777 -aF'\n' -ne '
    print for map join(" ", @$_),
              sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] 
                     || length($a->[1]) <=> length($b->[1])
                     || $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
              map [ split ],
              @F;
    ' input-file
```

- `-n` reads the input record by record
- `-0777` sets the whole file as one record
- `-l` adds newlines to prints
- `-a` splits the input
- `-F'\n'` tells `-a` to split on newlines
- each line is then split on whitespace by [split](http://p3rl.org/split), sorted numerically (`<=>`) by the 0th column, or by length of the 1st column, or alphabetically (`cmp`) by the first column

Comment: Sir thank you but... i dont understand a thing :D
Cant i use commands like "sort -k2 -k1" to first sort by second column, and then by first.
if you know more simple solution id be grateful.

Comment: @darkneess96: I've added some explanation.